# How to prevent a symlink from being removed?

Tags: linux, symlink

I cannot seem to work out how to protect a symbolic symlink from being deleted/removed or overwritten. Any ideas?

Comment: chmod ugo -w & chattr +i

Answer (score 2):

You need to deny access to the *directory* where symlink resides.

**EDIT:**

When you move/rename/delete a file in Unix based operating systems, you are modifying the directory in which they are located, not the files themselves. So permissions on the file don't matter at all.

Comment: But that would be overkill because there are files in the directory that are being worked with.

Comment: When you delete a symlink, is the same as you delete a normal file. The only permission checked are on the folder. You can limit access to the folder with a SELinux policy, or other mechanisms. But the main question is what is the real problem you are trying to solve?

Comment: I don't want a symlink to be type changed?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot change the permissions (or attributes) of a link, trying to do so is meaningless. From the chmod man page

> chmod  never  changes the permissions of symbolic links; the chmod system call cannot change their permissions.  This is not a problem since the permissions of symbolic links are never used.  However, for each symbolic link listed on the command line, chmod changes the permissions of the pointed-to file.