# Stop Apache Traffic Server from creating config file backups

Tags: redhat, rhel6, apache-traffic-server

I've got an installation of Apache Traffic Server running.  All is great, except it keeps overwriting my symlinked configuration files!

For failover purposes, I've replaced `records.config` and `remap.config` with symlinks to a shared storage location (so the active and standby servers can access the same config files).  The probably is ATS randomly(?) moves my symlinks to a backup file (e.g. `records.config_1`) and replaces the original with a new (non-symlinked) copy of the configuration file.

In other words, my `/etc/trafficserver/` directory will look like this one day:

```
[..]
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root    39 Nov 22 16:24 records.config -> /mnt/shared_storage/web/ats//records.config
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root    34 Nov 22 16:20 regex.map -> /mnt/shared_storage/web/ats//regex.map
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root    37 Nov 22 16:24 remap.config -> /mnt/shared_storage/web/ats//remap.config
[...]
```

...and a few weeks later, will become this:

```
[..]
-rw-r--r--.  1 ats  ats   12K Dec 26 11:55 records.config
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root    39 Nov 22 16:24 records.config_1 -> /mnt/shared_storage/web/ats//records.config
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root    34 Nov 22 16:20 regex.map -> /mnt/shared_storage/web/ats//regex.map
-rw-r--r--.  1 ats  ats   233 Dec 26 11:37 remap.config
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root    37 Nov 22 16:24 remap.config_1 -> /mnt/shared_storage/web/ats//remap.config
[...]
```

How can I stop ATS from performing these config file backups?  I need to reliably reference the shared storage for these configuration files so I can ensure my standby servers are referencing an updated configuration.

Note: I'm running Apache Traffic Server 5.3 on RHEL6.  Both are up to date (from RHN / EPEL).

Comment: I would be inclined to just set the immutable bit on these symlinks.

Comment: Hmmm, didn't think of that.  I'll give it a try while we wait to see if ATS can be configured to stop being annoying ;)

Comment: @TimBrigham ha, actually turns out you can't set immuteable on symlinks... but that led me to this which works pretty well so far: https://serverfault.com/a/741460/227710